# Cannot update parent state on clean up child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

cannot reset value on unmount. On mount, it can setValue {a:2}. but on unmount component, setValue is not resetting value,

```
const Child = ({setValue}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue({a:2})

    //clean up on unmount
    return () => {
      console.log('cleanup');
      setValue({});
    };
  }, []);
 }
```

In parent

```
 const Parent = () => {
   const [value, setValue ] = useState({})
   console.log(value) // returns {a:2} even after unmounting child
}
```

component unmounted and clean up also called console.log('cleanup'); but setValue can't reset.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. How do you send props to Child?

Comment: otherValue && <Child setValue={setValue} /> 
Obviously there was not issue sending the props as it can update to {a:2} on mount.